# Bayesian model comparison using cross-validation when models are functions of different variables

Tags: bayesian, cross-validation, model-selection, pymc

I'm trying to compare the predictive power of different models (in PyMC3) using Leave-One-Out Cross-Validation. Most models are in the form $y = f(x)$, but one important model is in the form $x = g(y)$. The latter does happen to fit well, but the LOO score is an order of magnitude better, which is unrealistic. I assume it is because $x \in [0, 0.5)$ while $y \in [0, 500)$, roughly, so the magnitudes of the errors of the two kinds of models differ significantly.

Is it possible to use LOO-CV (or information criteria) for such a case?

Comment: would it be possible to compare using information criteria such as DIC or Bayes Factors?

Comment: @bdeonovic, As I understand it the information criteria would suffer from the same problem. The WAIC (which I understand is the preferred criterion, and is also the one implemented in PyMC3) approaches LOO-CV asymptotically, and would still base its log predictive density on p(y|theta), or in the case of the g(y) model, on p(x|theta).

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that different scales explains the large difference. By scaling x and y to have similar scale you could learn which task is easier: modeling y|x or x|y (there are papers trying to identify which one of these has additive noise model which would give a hint on causal direction), but it would not solve your problem if you are interested in estimating the predictive performance for y.